# difflib.SequenceMatcher not returning unique ratio

Tags: python, gis, arcpy, difflib, sequencematcher

I am trying to compare 2 street networks  and when i run this code it returns a a ratio of .253529...  i need it to compare each row to get a unique value so i can query out the streets that dont match. What can i do it get it to return unique ratio values  per row?

```
# Set local variables
inFeatures = gp.GetParameterAsText(0)
fieldName = gp.GetParameterAsText(1)
fieldName1 = gp.GetParameterAsText(2)
fieldName2 = gp.GetParameterAsText(3)
expression = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,fieldName1,fieldName2).ratio()
```

# Execute CalculateField 
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(inFeatures, fieldName, expression, "PYTHON_9.3")

Comment: What is your question? what is gp?

Comment: What do you mean by "unique value"? Give us an example of your desired output

Comment: I want it to give me  a index value of the similarities between the two street names. for example  if it is fieldname1   is Broad Street and fieldname 2 is Broad Street then the output would be 1.whereas  if the fieldname1 was Braod Sreet and fieldname 2 was Broad St the outcome would be lower than 1.

Comment: @StephenHolt, thats exactly what ```ration()``` will give you

Comment: @wnnmaw it is giving me a ratio but i need it to run for all of the streets not just one. the fieldnames have thousand of streets so i need it to give me an index value based for each specific row it is calcualting

Comment: @StephenHolt, so you want to compute the ratio for each line of the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know both files always have the exact same number of lines, a simple approach like this would work:

```
ratios = []

with open('fieldName1', 'r') as f1, open('fieldName2', 'r') as f2:
    for l1, l2 in zip(f1, f2):
        R = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,l1,l2).ratio()
        ratios.append((l1, l2, R))
```

This will produce a list of tuples like this:

```
[("aa", "aa", 1), ("aa", "ab", 0.5), ...]
```

If your files are different sizes you'll need to find some way to match up the lines, or otherwise handle it